# What is the correct syntax for producing http links with custom text with pod2html?

Tags: perl, perl-pod

The `perlpod` documentation tells me that I can link to URLs using
`L<scheme:...>` or `L<text|scheme:...>`, it even lists `L<The Perl
Home Page|http://www.perl.org/>` as an example.

The first case works fine for me: `pod2html` turns

```
L<http://example.com/>
```

into

```
<a href="http://example.com/">http://example.com/</a>
```

But it fails on

```
L<example|http://example.com/>
```

which is just turned into

```
<em>example</em>
```

along with a warning:

```
/usr/bin/pod2html: : cannot resolve L<example|http://example.com/> in paragraph 2.
```

I would have expected something like

```
<a href="http://example.com/">example</a>
```

to be produced. How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE** So this seems to be a bug in `Pod::Html` as Alan Haggai Alavi points out. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

It indeed *was* a bug in [`Pod::Html`](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod::Html). It has been fixed in bleadperl.

Now `L<example|http://example.com/>` gets converted to `<a href="http://example.com/">example</a>`.

Since [`Pod::Html`](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod::Html) is a pure Perl module, [the files can be copied from bleadperl](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/tree/HEAD:/ext/Pod-Html) which will give you version 1.12. The module shipped with with perl<sup>**v5.14.2**</sup> is version 1.11 and exhibits this bug.

Else, you can use [`Pod::Simple::Html`](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod::Simple::HTML) which works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

use it like

```
L<< example|http://example.com/ >>
```

Comment: I tried that before posting the original question. Didn't work.